# Is it possible convert 'Primary' partition to 'Extend' partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition

I'm using CentOS 7 mini version. I'm still learning Linux. As you may know Linux can create 4 'Primary' partitions maximum. I tried to create 4 'Primary' partitions on a physical disk. I'm curious is it possible to change a 'Primary' partition to 'Extend' partition w/o delete the partition?

Following is my *fdisk* output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x98e83b49

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    52430847    26214400   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        52430848   104859647    26214400   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3       104859648   146802687    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sdb4       146802688   188745727    20971520    0  Empty
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything in your “empty” partition 4?

Comment: No data. It's for testing purpose. I only created 'extend' partition 4. Not yet create any 'logical' partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. An extended partition is simply an enumeration of logical partitions and contains no user data itself.

Any tool that purports to convert primary partitions into logical (not extended) partitions does so by moving the data before changing all the structures, since it is not as simple as simply flipping a bit to change the type.

Also, the 4-partition limit is part of the MBR partition scheme, not any particular OS; GPT supports many more partitions without any "extended" partitions, but requires a modern BIOS in order to be used (or a bootloader that can take over where the BIOS leaves off).

Comment: Actually, if there is enough room, one can rewrite the structures around the disc slices without having to relocate them.  Rod Smith's `fixparts` does this.  There isn't enough room in this case.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is wrong. Even when there's no space left between the partitions, shrinking the partitions at the end is trivial and usually requires moving no data.